# Android Webview Hangs while Loading Bing Maps

Tags: android, android-webview, xamarin.android, xamarin, bing-maps

I am using Bing Maps Custom Map URL in a Xamarin Android application WebView.

```
 _bingWebView = FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.bing_web_view);
_bingWebView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
_bingWebView.SetWebChromeClient (new AppWebChromeClient ());
_bingWebView.SetWebViewClient (new AppWebViewClient ());
_bingWebView.ClearCache (true);
_bingWebView.DestroyDrawingCache ();                
var propertyUrl = "http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?where1=" + _propertyUrlString.Trim () + "&style=a";
_bingWebView.LoadUrl (propertyUrl);
```

The Url is loading properly in some Android devices but in some devices it doesnt. It loads up for some addresses and for some addresses it doesnt. The page loads and it gets stuck on "Just a Moment" text on the left hand side. Further, If I close the activity, no other webview in my application loads up and comes up with a white background.
In the logs, I can see "nativeOnDraw failed, clearing to background color."
I think its an issue with Bing Maps. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you destroying drawing cache? What API are the devices using that are not working?

Comment: There are a bunch of known bugs in the android browser which causes issues with Bing Maps.

Comment: rbrundritt, care to provide a link to the known bugs? Aniket may find it useful to check that they haven't run into one of them.

Comment: @rbrundritt Yes it will be really helpful.
Cheesebaron - I am destroying the drawing cache because on some devices changing orientation multiple times and trying to build the drawing cache again to take a screenshot crashes the application. I am not using any API as of such.

Comment: The latest version of Android is using an older version of Chrome as it's browser (I believe v28). Chrome is currently at v32 so this means that any bugs fixed between these versions are not in Android.